# Function that generates 2 indexes for nested subsets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

I'm doing a problem and looking for some way to create a specific bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and my set $W$. $W$ is a set that contains infinite subsets $Y_n$. Each of these subsets contains every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ that adds up to $n$. I already know that each set $Y_n$ contains $\frac{n+ (n \mod 2)}{2}$ many subsets, which means that I basically already have the 2nd index which indexes the sets within $Y_n$. Now the first index needs to follow the following pattern:

| x | n for $Y_n$ |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 8 | 5 |
| 9 | 5 |

It follows this pattern: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BujFv.jpg

Does this function exist at all? If not, what could be some alternatives?

Comment: If such a function exists, no doubt it'd be closely tied to combinatorics and generating functions. Unfortunately, I cannot help more than that since I do not see the pattern (maybe enumerate some examples for $x\ge 4$?) Since you can generate more numbers, I highly recommend using the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/). Given your table, there were [19 decent matches among 27 total results](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C3%2C3%2C4%2C4%2C5%2C5%2C5&sort=&language=&go=Search).

Answer (score 1):

Just for some closure on this, I experimented a bit in Python and came up with this code to generate the sequence:

```
def make_special_points(x) -> list[int]:
    points = []
    num_counter = 1
    for i in range(1, x):
        for j in range(0, num_counter):
            points.append(i)
        if i % 2 == 0:
            num_counter += 1
    return points
```

I then plotted this code and played around with some functions that looked similar, until something looked "somewhat" correct. I then plotted the difference between the new function and my sequence to fine tune the answer. Turns out, my sequence can be exactly generated via the following formula:
$$ a(n) =  \lceil 2 \sqrt{n+1} \rceil - 1$$
Which is [integer sequence A000267](https://oeis.org/A000267).